# simple rake file manipulation

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm using rake 0.8.7

I want to run a simple rake task that unzips a file called pma.zip

here's my task

```
task :unzip_pma do
  file "pma.txt" => "pma.zip" do
    sh "unzip pma.zip"
  end
end
```

pma.txt is supposed to be the file that pma.zip is unzipped "into".  i.e., the creation of pma.txt is dependent on the existence of pma.zip.

however, when I run rake unzip_pma, there is no unzipping taking place, so my guess is that my syntax isn't correct.

```
rake unzip_pma -t -v
(in /Users/abdfadf/Desktop)
** Invoke unzip_pma (first_time)
** Execute unzip_pma
```

Question 1. What am I doing wrong.
Question 2. Is there some way to get more meaningful output than what I see when I run a trace on my rake command?

THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the generated file *is* the task-name.  You can then feed that task name as a dependency into another task. Try defining your rake tasks like this:

```
file "pma.txt" => "pma.zip" do
  sh "unzip pma.zip"
end

task :unzip_pma => "pma.txt" do
  # Other actions can go here...
end
```

With the above in your rakefile, you could also just run:

```
rake pma.txt
```

If you want to force one task to run inside another (instead of using a dependency rule), use `Rake::Task[:the_other_task].invoke`